# Repeated columns in cte

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fc99/1

I am getting repeated column in following ctc need help.

```
with RSFC(EMPID,ENAME,MGRID,LVL,SAL) as(
  select EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,MANAGER_ID,0 as LVL,SALARY from COMPANY
  where MANAGER_ID is null
  union all
  select EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,MANAGER_ID,LVL+1,SALARY from RSFC R
  inner join COMPANY F
  on F.MANAGER_ID = R.EMPID
)
cycle SAL set IS_CYCLE to 'Y' default 'N'
select * from RSFC
```

result

```
         EMPID ENAME                                                   MGRID        LVL        SAL IS_CYCLE
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------
         1 FRED                                                                   0     100000 N        
         1 FRED                                                                   0     100000 N        
         2 BARNEY                                                      1          1      50000 N        
         2 BARNEY                                                      1          1      50000 N        
         3 WILMA                                                       1          1      50000 N
```

Comment: Do you mean repeated columns or rows?  You can solve repeated rows by using `select distinct`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fc99/1     hear you can find the problem..

Comment: I don't want to use distinct... I think there is some problems in joins or table .. plz look @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fc99/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that "Fred" appears twice in the data, with the same id.  I would suggest that the `EmployeeId` be made a primary key (and hence unique).  In fact, the table should probably be called `Employees` and not `Company`.

You can fix your query just by getting distinct values:

```
with employees as (
      select distinct *
      from company
     ),
     RSFC(EMPID,ENAME,MGRID,LVL,SAL) as(
      select EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,MANAGER_ID,0 as LVL,SALARY
      from employees
      where MANAGER_ID is null
      union all
      select EMPLOYEE_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,MANAGER_ID,LVL+1,SALARY
      from RSFC R inner join
           employees F
           on F.MANAGER_ID = R.EMPID
     )
cycle SAL set IS_CYCLE to 'Y' default 'N'
select * from RSFC;
```